# Can an MSI remove bootstrapper entry in Control Panel?

Tags: wix, bootstrapper

I have a bootstrapper that only wraps one MSI. I might prefer to give the MSI to customers who I know have already run the bootstrapper and have the prerequisites installed. But running the MSI leaves the original entry in Control Panel alongside the new one, even though the UpgradeCode code is the same for Bundle and Product.

I understand there are some issues here - the bootstrapper is not the MSI, and in fact may contain more than one MSI. So I imagine this is actually expected behavior.

Is what I want to do just considered a bad idea? Should customers who install with a bootstrapper always upgrade with a bootstrapper?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you don't upgrade a bundle with another bundle, the old bundle's registration (more than just an ARP entry) and package cache is left behind. So yes, standard behavior is to upgrade with a newer bundle. If you are just trying to save download bandwidth, you can distribute an uncompressed bundle (just the bundle .exe with no embedded packages); only the necessary payloads will be downloaded and you won't waste bandwidth downloading prerequisites that are already installed.

Comment: I tried to mark your answer as correct but I guess I can't do that. (: